# Order by created date In Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, bigdata, database

i have problem with ordering data in **cassandra** **Database**.
this is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
    id uuid,
    created_at timestamp,
    comment_enabled boolean,
    content text,
    enabled boolean,
    meta map<text, text>,
    post_type tinyint,
    summary text,
    title text,
    updated_at timestamp,
    url text,
    user_id uuid,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, created_at)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (created_at DESC)
```

and when i run this **query**, i got the following message:

**Query**:

```
 select * from posts order by created_at desc;
```

**message**:

```
ORDER BY is only supported when the partition key is restricted by an EQ or an IN.
```

Or this query return data without sorting:

```
select * from posts
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear: you cannot `ORDER BY` without restricting the query with a `WHERE` clause. This is by design.

The data you get when running without a `WHERE` clause actually *are* ordered, not with your clustering key, but by applying the [token function](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/paging_c.html) to your partition key. You can verify the order by issuing:

```
SELECT token(id), id, created_at, user_id FROM posts;
```

where the `token` function arguments **exactly match your PARTITION KEY**.

I suggest you to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24953331/6570821)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39840707/6570821) to understand what you can/can't do.

Comment: you mean this query should return data ordered by default?

Comment: i tried this query but unfortunately the same output (data without sorting)

Comment: I mean exactly what I wrote: this query *already returns* data ordered by the token(id) function.

Comment: @HametGholizadeh You can't unless you also provide a partition key in your `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 5):

There are couple of things you need to understand,
In your case the partition key is "id" and the clustering key is "created_at".

what that essentially means is any row will be stored in a partition based on the hash of "id"(depending on your hashing scheme by default it is  Murmur3), now inside that partition the data is sorted based on your clustering key, in your case "created_at".

So if you query some data from that table by default the results which come are sorted based on your clustering order and the default sort order is the one which you specify while creating the table. However there is a gotcha there.

**If yo do not specify the partition key in the WHERE clause, the actual order of the result set then becomes dependent on the hashed values of partition key(in your case id)**.

So in order to get the posts by that specific order. you have to specify the partition key like this

> select * from posts WHERE id=1 order by created_at desc;

Note:

> It is not necessary to specify the ORDER BY clause on a query if your desired sort direction (“ASCending/DESCending”) already matches the CLUSTERING ORDER in the table definition.

So essentially the above query is same as

> select * from posts WHERE id=1

You can read more about this here http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/we-shall-have-order

Comment: Excellent explanation.  Also, +1 for linking my article!

Comment: tnQ, it's really helped me ♥