# Migrating selected rows between Cassandra databases

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3, cassandra-3.0

I have 2 Cassandra databases and on each database I have a table with the same schema (t1 and t2). 
I need to copy some rows from one table to the other. What's the best approach to do so using the Java driver?

```
                    Select select = QueryBuilder.select().all().from(keyspace, table);
                    select.where(clause);
                    for (Row row : results) {
                            Insert insert = QueryBuilder.insertInto(keyspace, table);
                            for(Column c: columns)
                            {
                                insert.value(c.column_name, row.getObject(c.column_name));
                            }
                            dstSession.execute(insert);
                        }
```

Should I just do a select and then get all values for each row and then do an insert or is there a more efficient way?

Comment: You could also use the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43274928/copy-data-from-one-table-to-other-in-cassandra-using-java),

Comment: Why don't you use cqlsh copy command to do so ?

Comment: As I understand it Hossein doesn't want all data from a table, but rather the selected rows in the where clause. I believe that is not possible with using only COPY command. However you could use COPY and then filter the data file yourself with sed or awk. However I don't see any advantage of doing that over what what you suggested yourself.

Comment: That's right, I don't want to move all data (that's super expensive bandwidth wise)

Answer (score 0):

Use stableloader to load those records in that particular sstable